# SPDX license warning

Tags: solidity, remix

Could anyone please help with the SPDX license warning shown in the graph below? I've seen this warning on and off again and again and again. I've tried all I can to remove it, but it is still there. The code is also shown so that you can see if there is any problem. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Remove the newline between SPDX and pragma declaration

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the saming warning is still there.

Comment: I just found out that it doesn't matter if you have that newline or not.

Comment: I think you just need to manually hit "Compile multiCall.sol".

Comment: Weird enough, as you can see in the graph below the "Compile" button, it says no contract compiled yet. That means the blue button does not work.

Comment: Start a new browser session and re-create the file. Storage bugs happen for me as well sometimes.

Comment: Remix IDE team should have been aware of this issue by now, if this is a common issue.

Comment: @scorpion9979 No, it does not work, it does have something to do with http:// or https://, and I tried both. https:// seems to be working more stable, although sometimes can get totally frozen.